# Jetty 6: Unknown Error 99

Tags: java, php, http, curl, jetty

The system I'm developing is comprised of a jetty server (v6.1.2rc4) and a php frontend that sends http requests to jetty via curl_exec.
**The server and the client are on the same machine**.

The requests I send can be both POSTs and GETs, I get the same error for either which is:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1: Unknown error 99
```

This is rather cryptic.

It seems that after the first problematic request, some of the following (unrelated) requests also get corrupted.

It looks like jetty is simply refusing the connection, but I can't read more than that into the error message.

I thought it was a problem with the server's configuration, so I tried changing jetty's maxIdleTimeMs, but without success.

Any idea about what to do is welcome

thanks,

Silvio

**EDIT:** I get the error after the server has already answered some requests successfully

Comment: did you verify that jetty is actually listening on the right port using netstat?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's up and running on the right port, because it responds to some http requests before giving the error. I'll double check with netstat anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check that your Jetty server is actually running - you probably have another server running on port 80 (the default server port, and used by Apache and IIS). Configure Jetty to listen to port 8080 or something (or your other server).

Comment: I discovered it was crashing after running for a while, due to server side memory management issues